# Парсинг Json стандартными средствами либо небольшой класс без доп библиотек

Tags: c#, json

Существует проблема добавления `dll` библиотеки в `unity3d`, поэтому встал такой глупый вопрос, возможно ли реализовать чтение и дальнейший парсинг `Json` файла стандартными средствами или может есть для этого класс.

`Json` имеет очень простую структуру

```
{
   [ 
      "name":"name",
      "count":"count"
   ],
   [
      ...
   ]
}
```

ps: скачал `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` менеджере `NuGet`, но в ссылках он не появляется почему то там висит только `System.Runtime.Serialization`

pss: нашел его в компонентах `System.Runtime.Serialization` в анализаторе, но в юнити все равно висит ошибка

> The type or namespace name "Json" does not exist in the namespace `System.Runtime.Serialization`

Вот как так может быть не понимаю

Comment: Есть стандартная библиотека System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Comment: @dmepty буквально за пару секунд до вашего комментария обновил вопрос.. можете что нибудь подсказать по этому поводу?

Comment: Советую вам разобраться с подключением библиотек, а там уже отпадут все эти вопросы. Какой у вас Unity (версия)? Попробую поставить, воспроизвести вашу проблему...

Comment: Просто нужно добавить ссылку на System.Runtime.Serialization.dll в проект

Comment: @EvgeniyZ версия 5.6.1. я уже и через импорт  в Asset добавлял, все что нашел попробовал ничто не помогает. Может причина в отсутствии .NET 3.5?

Comment: А чем плох Newtonsoft.Json? Он работает на 2й версии дотнета.

Comment: @Yami вот лично я прям очень за него, но мне никак не импортировать его в юнити не могу найти причину. Добавляю в студии ссылку сохраняю юнити орет что не найдено пространство имен, захожу опять в студию ее уже там нету. Импортировал прямо в юнити в папку Plugins подключал ссылку на дллку эффекта ноль

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот просто ввел в `Yandex` `unity json.net`.

Что нашел?

1. [Adding Json.Net to a Unity3D project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398407/adding-json-net-to-a-unity3d-project)
2. [JSON .NET For Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347)
3. [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON)

Comment: Поддерживаю, только что установил указанную версию, зашел в маркет Unity, поставил от туда JSON .NET For Unity и все отлично встало.

Comment: Я прочиталь мельком про Json.Net то что он платный и отбросил этот вариант.. Так ли это?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров json.net - это тот же Newtonsoft.Json. Цены вроде только для их Schema компонента и то, для коммерческих целей.